# Android: enable second checkbox only if first is selected

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am using a custom array adapter and have two checkboxes on the same line.  The second one should only be enabled if the first one is checked.  I don't see how to get a handle to the second list box from the onClickListener of the first one.

```
    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DiatonicMajorKey> {

    private ArrayList<DiatonicMajorKey> keyList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<DiatonicMajorKey> keyList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, keyList);
        this.keyList = new ArrayList<DiatonicMajorKey>();
        this.keyList.addAll(keyList);
    }

    // this class holds the items that actually appear on the screen.
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox key;
        CheckBox inversion;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.key_info, null);


            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.keycode);
            holder.key = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.inversion = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.key.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    DiatonicMajorKey _key = (DiatonicMajorKey) cb.getTag();
                    _key.setKeySelected(cb.isChecked());

                    // how to get handle of inversion checkbox to enable/disable it
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it:

```
            final CheckBox other=holder.inversion;

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.inversion.setEnabled(false);

            // set checkchanged listener to your first checkbox
            holder.key.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        //enable if the first checkbox is checked/ticked
                        other.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });


            holder.key.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    DiatonicMajorKey _key = (DiatonicMajorKey) cb.getTag();
                    _key.setKeySelected(cb.isChecked());

                    // handle of inversion checkbox to enable/disable it
                    other.setEnabled(cb.isChecked());
                    other.setChecked(false);
                }
            });
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have two checkboxes named checkBoxFirst and checkBoxSecond.

```
checkBoxFirst.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxSecond.setEnabled(isChecked);
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 //initialize the second checkbox and set enabled to false 
 holder.inversion.setEnabled(false);

  // set checkchanged listener to your first checkbox
    holder.key.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
               //enable if the first checkbox is checked/ticked
                holder.inversion.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: But if one is doing this from within an inner class in getView, then I get the error message "variable holder is accessed from within an inner class, needs to be declared final."  But if declared final, no value can be assigned to it.  Catch-22.

Comment: Still a no go.  

    //initialize the second checkbox and set enabled to false 
     holder.inversion.setEnabled(false);

The second checkbox needs to be enabled if the first one is checked.  I am still trying to find how to get a handle to the first checkbox in an individual line.

but

Answer (score 0):

Change your getView method with:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.key_info, null);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.keycode);
        holder.key = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        holder.inversion = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        // set initial status of checkbox inversion
        holder.inversion.setEnabled(cb.isChecked());
        // get final reference, used in onclick listener
        final CheckBox other=holder.inversion;

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.key.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                DiatonicMajorKey _key = (DiatonicMajorKey) cb.getTag();
                _key.setKeySelected(cb.isChecked());

                // handle of inversion checkbox to enable/disable it
                other.setEnabled(cb.isChecked());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I just add initialization code for second checkbox and i use a final reference in the listener to manage checkbox status.

Comment: I can't set the initial status 

    holder.inversion.setEnabled(cb.isChecked()); 

because cb has not yet been defined.

Comment: holder.inversion.setEnabled(cb.isChecked()); take defined status in xml. If you prefer, you can directly set to true (or false)